# Valid Java code that is NOT valid Groovy code?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Most Java code is also syntactically valid Groovy code. However, there are a few exceptions which leads me to my question:

Which constructs/features in Java are syntactically invalid in Groovy? **Please provide concrete examples of Java code (Java 1.6) that is NOT valid Groovy code (Groovy 1.6).**

**Update:**

So far we've got five examples of syntactically valid Java code that is not valid Groovy code:

1. Array initializations
2. Inner classes
3. `def` is a keyword in Groovy, but not in Java
4. `"$$"`-strings - parsed as an invalid `GString`s in Groovy
5. Non-static initialization blocks `-- class Foo { Integer x; { x = 1; } }`

Is this the complete list? Any further examples?

**Update #1:** I've started a bounty to bump this question. The bounty will be granted to the person who provides the most comprehensive list of examples. So far we've uncovered five examples, but I'm sure there a quite some more out there. So keep them coming!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is a list of items that are valid Java 6, but not valid Groovy 1.6. This isn't a complete list, but I think it covers most of the cases. Some of these are permitted by later Groovy versions as noted below.

(By the way, I think you should note that non-static initialization blocks DO work in Groovy.)

**Any inner class declaration in Groovy 1.6 ([1.7 added inner classes](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-1.7.html)):**

including static,

```
public class Outer{
  static class Inner{}
}
```

non-static,

```
public class Outer{
  class Inner{}
}
```

local classes,

```
public class Outer{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    class Local{}  
  }
}
```

and anonymous classes

```
java.util.EventListener listener=new java.util.EventListener(){};
```

**Using Groovy keywords as variables won't work in any Groovy version:**

```
int def;
int in;
int threadsafe;
int as;
```

**Java array initialization**

```
String[] stuff=new String[]{"string"};
int[] array={1,2,3};
```

Use the Groovy array-literal format by changing `{...}` to `[...]`.

**Using dollar signs in strings where what follows isn't a valid expression**

```
String s="$$";
String s="$def";
String s="$enum";
String s="$;";
String s="$\\";
//etc.
```

**More than one initializer in a for loop**

```
for (int i=0, j=0; i < 5; i++) {}
```

**More than one increment in a for loop**

```
int j=0;
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++,j++) {}
```

**Breaking up some expressions using newlines**

```
int a= 2 
/ 2 
;
```

Hint: use a backslash line-continuation in Groovy

```
int a= 2 \
/ 2 \
;
```

**Ending switch with a case that has no body**

```
switch(a){
  case 1:
}
```

**Having a default in a switch with no body**

Applies in both cases where default is at the end

```
int a=0;
switch(a){
    default:
}
```

or somewhere in the middle

```
switch(a){
    default:
    case 1:
        break;
}
```

**Annotations with lists**

```
@SuppressWarnings({"boxing","cast"})
```

Hint: use Groovy list-literal syntax instead:

```
@SuppressWarnings(["boxing","cast"])
```

**Native method declaration**

```
public native int nativeMethod();
```

**Class per enum in 1.6 (valid in later Groovy versions) **

```
public enum JavaEnum{
  ADD{
    public String getSymbol(){ return "+"; }
  };
  abstract String getSymbol();
}
```

**Do loop**

```
do{
  System.out.println("stuff");
}while(true);
```

**Equality**

While technically `==` is valid Groovy and Java, it's semantically different. It's one of the reasons you can't rely on just compiling Java as Groovy without changes. Worse, it might seem to work sometimes due to Java string interning.

The example was too long to add to an existing answer, but the point is that **Java code that's *syntatically* valid as Groovy might behave differently at runtime**.

To get the same result as Java's `x == y` for two not-null objects you need `x.is(y)` in Groovy. `x == y` is valid Groovy, it just *does something different*.

[The Groovy documentation has a more detailed and broader list of differences](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html).

Comment: It looks like the inner class example is no longer valid; Groovy supports inner classes now. See http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_creating_instances_of_non_static_inner_classes . Some of the others need a simple change to Groovy list-syntax, but are definitely invalid as written in Java form.

Answer (score 12):

Ok, heres one point:

```
int[] i = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

That is good syntax in java, bad in groovy.

I don't think you want to assume any given java code will be equivalent in groovy.  [This site](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html) describes some of the differences, which includes things as basic as == not meaning the same thing in both languages.  Also, static array initialization is different, and there are no anonymous inner classes.

This compiles fine in Java 1.6

```
public class Test2 {
    int[] i = { 0, 1, 2 };

    private class Class1 {
        public void method1() {
            if (i[2] == 2) {
                System.out.println("this works");
            }
        }
    }

    public void method1() {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.method1();
    }
}
```

But is so wrong in Groovy. It gives the following errors in Groovy 1.6:

```
unexpected token: 1 @ line 2, column 14.

Class definition not expected here. Possible attempt to use inner class. Inner classes not supported, perhaps try using a closure instead. at line: 4 column: 2.
```

If you fix those things, it does print what you expect, though.

If you're looking for newer language syntax issues, like generics or annotations, Groovy supports both of those, though not fully.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted, but: that's not what was asked. Nobody said Java code would be equivalent in groovy. The question was what snytactically valid Java code is not syntactically valid in Groovy.

Comment: I do not interpret the question that way: "Which constructs/features in Java are not supported in Groovy?" I read that as behave differently.  Perhaps the question needs to be clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Multidimensional arrays, where size is not specified.

```
def x=new Object[5][];  // ERROR: expression expected 

def x=new Object[5][2]; // this works
```

Comment: This is supported in later Groovy versions by the looks.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the answer by Peter Dolberg:

Besides valid Java code that is not valid in Groovy, you also need to be wary of code that is valid in both Java and Groovy, but has different results in Groovy. Obvious examples are char literals and GStrings:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf('3' + 3)); // 54 in Java, 33 in Groovy (arithmetic ascii value vs. String concat)

System.out.println("${3+4}");
```

Implicit accessors:

```
class Foo {public static int counter; public static int bar; public static void getBar() {counter++; return bar;}}
System.out.println(Foo.bar);
System.out.println(Foo.counter); // 0 in Java, 1 in Groovy
```

toString() has been overwritten by GroovyDefaultMethods, which can bite you when you parse the result.

```
Map someMap = new HashMap();
someMap.put("a", "b")
someMap.toString();
```

The equals operation

```
"foo" == "foo"
class Foo {public boolean equals() {return true;}}
new Foo() == new Foo()
```

Some operator precedence:

```
a *= b/100; // Groovy: (a *= b)/100; Java: a *= (b/100);
```

This is not a correct answer to the original question, since the groovy code is still syntactically valid in itself, but since it has a different result, I think it is worthwhile mentioning it here. The result is that algorithmically, a method may return the wrong(invalid) result when copied from Java to Groovy.

Comment: Equality is definitely a big trap

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of for now:

- `int def;`
- `String s = "$$";`

Answer (score 1):

Has anyone mention the difference in ==? I took this is from Grails documentation.

== means equals on all types. In Java there's a wierd part of the syntax where == means equality for primitive types and == means identity for objects.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring an array of a given type using [] after the variable name instead of the type works in Java but not Groovy.

`byte[] buff = new byte[1024]; // Works`

`byte buff[] = new byte[1024]; // Not Groovy`

Results in Primitive type literal: byte cannot be used as a method name

Answer (score 0):

Non-static initialization blocks:

```
class Foo {
  Integer x;   
  { x = 1; }
}
```

UPDATE: This is in fact valid Groovy code.

Comment: The heck?  I didn't know that was valid Java, either.

Comment: Testing confirms that it is indeed run whenever an instance of the class is created.  Freaky.  The more you know.

Comment: This DOES work in Groovy. At least it works in both Groovy 1.5.7 and 1.6.

Comment: hmm, it does work for me too. I could have sworn this used to not work. Oh well, down vote the answer.

Comment: Worth an upvote; some people didn't know that this worked on Java, and you corrected to say this actually works on Groovy too. :3