# Groovy vs. Java syntax discrepancy

Tags: java, syntax, groovy

In Java I can do this:

```
return a
    && b
    && c;
```

In Groovy, it returns a compile error: `unexpected token: &&`. It also occurs if I omit the `return` keyword in Groovy. However if I wrap the statement in parentheses, it works fine.

In all the Groovy resources I've read, I've been told that I should be able to write "straight Java" wherever I want. Is this a bug? If not, what is the reason for this design decision?

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687601/valid-java-code-that-is-not-valid-groovy-code), but did not find this issue listed. I understand that there are some things that *cannot* be inherited from Java, but this wouldn't seem like one of those things.

Comment: +1 It's a very interesting question, but largely of academic interest. In practice, this would be a highly unusual way to write a return statement

Comment: True, for the most part. I'd say there's some validity for `a`, `b`, and `c` sufficiently ugly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that Groovy doesn't require explicit line terminators - and `return a` looks like a valid statement on its own. You could use:

```
return a &&
       b &&
       c;
```

Or use a line continuation:

```
return a \
    && b \
    && c;
```

It's *not* true that all Java is valid Groovy. While most Java syntax is covered, occasionally a feature of Groovy will have an impact on valid Java.

Answer (score 9):

Groovy doesn't seem to require semicolons, so I think your code is being intepreted like:

```
return a;
    && b;
    && c;
```

From [the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Statements):

> Groovy uses a similar syntax to Java although in Groovy semicolons are optional.
>
> This saves a little typing but also makes code look much cleaner (surprisingly so for such a minor change). So normally **if one statement is on each line** you can ommit semicolons altogether - though its no problem to use them if you want to. If you want to put multiple statements on a line use a semicolon to separate the statements.

Answer (score 2):

you can do almost all java in groovy except you look at the following.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java

if you want to do straight java then you can do it in a *.java class and drop it into the src folder.

Comment: I've seen this page, and my issue isn't addressed there.

Comment: it kind of dances around it
Things to be aware of
Semicolons are optional. Use them if you like (though you must use them to put several statements on one line).

Comment: Yes I already know that semicolons are optional... this isn't helpful. And using a semi-colon here doesn't even solve the issue.

Comment: the basic problem is the groovy compiler does not recognize that the line is continued on the next line you need something to tell the compiler that the line is continued